# complicated combinatorial algorithms with good descriptions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, soft-question

For educational purposes, I am looking for an example of a complicated, elementary, but very well-explained combinatorial algorithm.

Such an example might be a bijection between two easily described sets, where the bijection involves many case distinctions.

Of course, "very well-explained" is completely subjective, but that is really the focus of the question.

Comment: what about [Schensted insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%E2%80%93Schensted_correspondence#Insertion)?

Comment: @ChristianStump: no, sorry, that's *way* too short and natural.  I am looking for something that takes a full page of pseudocode, and contains several case distinctions. One problem I am facing is that I cannot know whether the algorithm has a simpler description.  So a reference with a well explained algorithm, that was simplified later, would be fine.  For comparison, even the detailed pseudocode for Schensted insertion on wikipedia is just five lines.

Comment: How about Hopcroft-Karp algorithm for bipartite matching?  Gerhard "Is Seven Pseudocode Lines Enough?" Paseman, 2018.05.25.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: no, sorry, it should be about a page. The point is that a student of mine has a bijection which solves a relatively old problem, but the algorithm is, to my eyes, terribly complicated. We checked it by computer (although the first interesting cases appear for standard Young tableaux with about 30 entries, so there are too many to check them all), and the proof looks correct. So the question is how to sell it. Thus I was hoping for an educational example, the focus being on the quality of the exposition.

Comment: I don't really see this sort of length as a problem. If you're not trying to compress (i.e. you write readable pseudocode), the Blossom Algorithm is about a page of pseudocode. The (original) maximum weight matching algorithm uses Blossom as a subroutine, so it's somewhat longer. There are many much longer modern algorithms. Usually the best idea is to break up into subroutines, explain each, and then how to put them together.

Comment: @user36212: I just had a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm - indeed, that's exactly one example for what I was looking for! Although the algorithm is quite a bit shorter than what my student has to deal with, the exposition on the wikipedia page seems to illustrate good practice! Maybe you want to turn this into an answer?

Comment: This sounds like a non-issue to me.  You can only "sell" when you have a "product".  Bijections are useful as either a simple way to prove a known result or as a way to prove a refinement of such a result.  In the former case, having many complicated cases defeats the purpose.  In the latter - if you do have such a statistics it no longer matters how complicated is your bijection; just state the result upfront and proof at the end of the paper.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @IgorPak: I should have put the word "sell" under quotes. What I meant to say is, that I want to see examples where other people presented a truly complicated bijection in a way so that the reader can still appreciate it. (it is *not* my bijection, I am only advisor)

Comment: Have you ever tried to look at the algorithms that find if a given pattern (of length $m$) occurs in a given string (of length $n$ ) in better than $mn$ time? I like those and they seem to satisfy your criteria.

Comment: @fedja: are you thinking of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm, in particular, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm ? Yes, this looks helpful!  Thank you!

Comment: @MartinRubey Yes, those. Though I've seen better expositions (don't remember where :-( )

Comment: @fedja: in case you recall, that would be great!

Comment: I think Doyle and Qiu’s [Division by four](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01402) algorithm perhaps meets your criteria – also concisely and amusingly [explained by Rich Schwartz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.02179). Or even the earlier Doyle-Conway [Division by three](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605779).

Comment: @RobinHouston: Your mileage may vary. Schwartz's card-game explanation makes roughly zero sense to me.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I found it memorable and amusing, though I had to read the Doyle-Qiu paper as well in order to understand it completely. (So I think “roughly zero” is unfair – but definitely less than one.)

Answer (score 2):

I have a candidate. Let $\mathcal{A_n} = \{w \in S_n: w_1 = w_n+1, \mbox{Fl}(w_2 \dots w_{n-1}) \in \mathcal{A}_{n-2} \}$ where $\mbox{Fl}$ is the flatten operator mapping a word with distinct entries to the permutation with the same relative order.
In one of my [papers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.01823.pdf), we show that
$$
\sum_{w \in \mathcal{A}_{2n+1}} F_w  = s_{\delta_n}^2
$$
where $F_w$ is the Stanley symmetric function and $\delta_n = (n{-}1,n{-}2,\ldots,1)$ (a similar result holds for $\mathcal{A}_n$ with $n$ even).
We have since given two bijective proofs of this identity - one based on an insertion algorithm and the other based on a variant of the Little bijection.

What we don't mention is that I have a more or less complete document defining a bijection
$$
\mbox{SYT}(\delta_{2n}\setminus (n)^n) \to \mathcal{R}(n{+}1\ n \dots1 \ 2n{+}2\ 2n{+}1 \dots n{+}1)  \to \bigcup_{w \in \mathcal{A}_{2n+1}} \mathcal{R}(w)
$$
where $\mathcal{R}(w)$ is the set of reduced words of $w$.
The first arrow here follows immediately from the literature, but the second requires repeated application of a very precise choice of Little bumps.
My implementation of the algorithm in SAGE has a little over 100 lines of code (not counting an implementation of the quite technical Little bijection), mostly to describe which Little bumps to perform.
The description of the algorithm in the uncompleted paper takes about 2/3 of a page once all terminology has been established.
The three main steps call each other recursively and repeatedly, with various cases determining which step to return to.
Converting the description to pseudo-code would make it much longer.

One attractive feature of this map for your purposes is that it runs into quite subtle issues.
Initial attempts to code the bijection would usually succeed for instances of the problem with $n \sim 50$, while for $n \sim 100$ they tended to get caught in infinite loops.
With a few more major pieces of casework, the algorithm could be proved to terminate.
In the end, it was relatively easy to see the map is an injection, but I was missing a key technical lemma about Little bumps to show it was invertible.
Since better proofs are available, I will probably never write the full details, but I am happy to share a correct implementation or a complete description of the map.

Comment: Hi Zachary! This looks quite clearly like what I'm after, except possibly (how could I judge :-) for the "very well-explained" part... So, if you think you have a good description, maybe you want to send it to me by email, so my student (and certainly also me myself) can learn from it!

Answer (score 1):

I believe proposition 11 in [this paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v24i4p3/pdf) might fulfill your requirements - it describes a bijection between sets (certain fillings of tableaux).
The properties of the bijection actually defines it uniquely, so the steps to perform the algorithm is quite easy.

The kicker - to prove that it is indeed a bijection, that it works, requires induction between several sub and sub-sub cases. A second part of this check requires to check that it works on all $3\times 2$-diagrams, and relative orderings of the entries. This is a few cases to go through, where "a few" is about $280.000$ (we uses two independent computer programs to do these steps).

EDIT: Well, seeing your comment - you might also be interested in proofs that use some type of sign-reversing involution. This might sometimes involves some quite non-trivial case by case analysis, and you essentially describe an algorithm on how to do this.

My suggestion is to ask someone implement the bijection in a different language - sometimes an experienced math coder can gather several subcases into fewer ones by choosing some sneaky conventions (smart choice of indexing, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Per! Well, the point is really the complexity of the algorithm in question, and the question is how to make it accessible to the reader (and make the reader like it :-).  I tried for quite a while to simplify a special case of the algorithm (which was discovered first), and failed completely.  I couldn't make it shorter by a single line. I have little doubt that eventually a simpler algorithm may be found, but before that, the current algorithm must be presented.

Comment: @MartinRubey: Ah - is it easier to write the code in a functional language? A well-worked out example is great, but if the interesting stuff happens when you have 30 boxes or more... ugh..